# Python: Censoring a word in text but last word does not censor

Tags: python

I am doing Python on Codecademy trying to censor out a word in a text. The code works but if the last word in the text has the word, it will not be censored.

I believe the `for` statement needs altering such as `for x in (text + 1)` but of course that causes an error. We are not to use built-in functions such as `replace()` Any ideas?

```
def censor(text,word):
    text = text.split()
    for x in text:
        if x == word:
            text[text.index(x)] = "*" * len(word)
    return " ".join(text)

print(censor("You dirty guy and dirty boy dirty.", "dirty"))
```

This returns `[You ***** guy and ***** boy dirty.]`

Comment: I suggest you use `str.replace` or `re.sub`

Comment: I agree seems wierd you cant use replace but you can use split, index, len, join and print. All are built-ins

Comment: You could change your test to strip the punctuation: `if x.translate(None, string.punctuation) == word:`

Answer (score 18):

It's probably including the full stop in the last token, so it is comparing `"dirty."` with `"dirty"`.

Comment: Are you intentionally avoiding proposing a solution (since the question is in the context of Code Academy)?

Comment: Yes, I find its easier to learn when people point me to the answer but don't fully answer it.

Answer (score 14):

The last occurrence of dirty is `'dirty.'` instead of `'dirty'`.
It might be easier to use the `replace` function:

```
def censor(text,word):
    return text.replace(word, len(word)*'*')
```

Without built-in functions:

```
def censor(text,word):
    while 1:
        wordPosition = text.find(word)
        if wordPosition < 0:
            break
        text = text[:wordPosition] + len(word)*'*' + text[wordPosition+len(word):]
    return text
```

Comment: He did mention "We are not to use built-in functions such as replace()".

Comment: How does this handle cases where the word to censor might be part of a larger word?  For example, does 'ass' get censored only when it appears as a word, or does it also get censored in 'assassin'?

Comment: Yes, for now it will censor 'assassin' - you should implement a find function to look for real words ...

Answer (score 6):

Christopher is correct that it's comparing `dirty` to `dirty.` with a period.  As you said you cannot use `replace` function, so you could change your `if` statement to be

```
if x.startswith(word) == True:
```

Comment: If you extend this out to a profanity filter then the residents of [Crapstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crapstone) likely would not appreciate this approach

Comment: Just `if x.startswith(word):` please, there is no need for explicit comparisons to `True` or `False` in a Python if statement.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to the last dirty having `.` so thus, there's difference between dirty and dirty(.). Here is a way to tackle the problem :

```
def censor(text, word):
    wordlist = text.split()
    new_words_list = []
    for item in wordlist:
        if item.find(word) > -1:
            new_words_list.append( '*' * len(word))
        else:
            new_words_list.append(item)
    return " ".join(new_words_list)

print(censor("You dirty guy and dirty boy dirty.", "dirty"))
```

Output:

```
You ***** guy and ***** boy *****
```

Comment: Are you intentionally avoiding proposing a solution (since the question is in the context of Code Academy)?

Comment: @Darthfett Yeah.But I added code now to tackle the problem.Someone/OP might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use re.sub to replace the work from text

```
import re
re.sub("word", "new_replaced_word", text)
```